# Serving a django model containing objects

Tags: django, django-models

I have following django model:

```
class Weather(models.Model):

    lat_lng = gis_models.PointField()
    raw_data = psql_fields.JSONField(null=True)
```

I have following view:

```
def weather(request):
    data = WeatherModel.objects.all()
    js_data = serializers.serialize('json', data)
    return HttpResponse(js_data, content_type='application/json')
```

It throws error saying 'Point object is not json serializable.'
I want this function to return json.
Please help.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [django json serializer does not implement geojson](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4234540/django-json-serializer-does-not-implement-geojson)

Answer (score 0):

The default JSON serializer doesn't know how to serialize Point objects.

Derive your own from Django's encoder. You can also use `JsonResponse` for shorter code:

```
from django.contrib.gis.geos import Point
from django.core.serializers.json import DjangoJSONEncoder
from django.http import JsonResponse


class GeoJSONEncoder(DjangoJSONEncoder):
    def default(self, obj):
        if isinstance(obj, Point):
            return obj.coords
        return super().default(obj)


def weather(request):
    data = WeatherModel.objects.all()
    return JsonResponse(data, encoder=GeoJSONEncoder)
```

Comment: Thanks for the response
but it does not seem to work, at first it says queryset object is not serializable, I converted it to list(WeatherModel.objects.all())
now it asks to add safe=False
After that it says Weather object is not serialiazable.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [JsonResponse](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/request-response/#jsonresponse-objects) with [values](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.values).

```
from django.http import JsonResponse

def weather(request):
    data = list(WeatherModel.objects.all())
    js_data = serializers.serialize('json', data)
    return JsonResponse(data, safe=False)  # or JsonResponse({'data': data})
```

Modifed answer from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15874233/output-django-queryset-as-json).